# How to Scale SVG rectagle to fit the svg text element

Tags: text, formatting, svg

So here is the problem:

I am trying to create dynamic buttons that have text.  The text will be generated dynamically so the svg object doesn't know the size of the text.  There are two things that I am looking to do and I hope that SVG will do this

First I want the left and right edge of the svg element to stay the same even if I scale the element horizontally

[image: svg navigation problems]

[image: Expected results]

The problem is that I have to set a width on the svg otherwise it doesn't show up when I display the page.  Also on the Home and blog buttons you can see that the edge is compressed.  I want the edge to stay the same no matter how much text is in the element.

Also I can't seem to set the scale or width properly even with a javascript `.getComputedTextLength()`

Any help or a point in the right direction would be very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buttons that are sized to their text content is functionality that can be adressed with Raphael's getBBox()
The use of this js library means that you are implicitly using SVG or VML and this functionality is more easily addressed by referencing this JavaScript library
To see the getBBox() function in action you could visit the Autobox example here:

http://www.irunmywebsite.com/raphael/additionalhelp.php?v=2

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction but didn't resolve the issue entirely since the hover effect doesn't work with IE7 or IE8 with css from the raphael script